# DevExpress XtraGrid: How to force a datetime format that does not take the system's short/long date setting

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

In our company, the Windows regional settings for long date **and short** date are customized to always show the name of the day like this: "dddd dd MMMM yyyy" for "friday, April 12, 2012".

In our CRM software, we use a lot of DevExpress Component and in one of the XtraGrid, I would like to avoid the default system behavior and show a custom formating.

I did set my column to display the format type : "DateTime" and the FormatString: "G" as specified on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) but when I run the software it still show the system short date (friday, April 12, 2012)

Is there a way to force a Display format that does not uses the system default ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify any [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you want in the `DisplayFormat.FormatString` property. You're not limited to the standard format strings. For example, you could specify the column's format as:

```
FormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

and you would get standard US-style short date format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DateTime like this:

```
DateTime dtime = DateTime.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy");
```